# Can 3.5mm Headphone Jack of the laptop be used for multiple devices

Tags: audio, microphone, splitter

I am using a Surface pro 6 that has one 3.5 mm head phone jack .

i want to use this jack for connecting external mic (Boya BYM1 Omnidirectional Lavalier )  and external Speaker (JBL GO)

Both mic and speaker has 3.5mm Jack.  Both are working with 3.5 mm jack when connected independently. However i want to use both of them together.

I tried purchasing a audio splitter cable [Splitter Link](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07GT17CKT/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) however found that speaker is working but mic is not.

What am i doing wrong ? Is there a specific device that i should purchase to make both the audio input and audio output work with Surface pro 3.5 mm jack.

Comment: You should buy a usb to microphone or speaker jack converter. It is possible that your laptop doesn't support microphone and audio in one jack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the description of your
[Splitter Link](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07GT17CKT/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
I found this text:

> Please note: This splitter can not support external mic.

I believe this explains the problem - the device is not suitable for your needs.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which splitter works . Most product descriptions in Amazon is confusing

Comment: Sometimes the reviews help.